# Incanter dependency

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop, incanter

I am trying to implement the following link http://data-sorcery.org/category/pca/ and found myself stuck trying to load the necessary Incanter libraries, i.e.

```
(use '(incanter core stats charts datasets))
```

The only dependency that I have for Incanter is `[incanter "1.5.4"]`. Is this enough to load the libraries, am I just missing something?

I am not really sure how to load the 4 highlighted libraries in the link. To note I have been able to use Incanter previously in the REPL.

**Edit**: My text editor has the following

```
(ns my-namespace.filename
(:use [incanter.core]
      [incanter.stats]
      [incanter.charts]
      [incanter.datasets]))


(def iris (to-matrix (get-dataset :iris))) 
(view iris)
```

which returns the error `CompilerException javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: handshake alert: unrecognized_name, compiling:(pca.clj:11:22)`

The error seems to stem from the inner part, namely the get-dataset... which I am unsure how to fix.

Comment: I've updated the answer with solution to SSL problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes there is a confusion between the Incanter's libraries (that are included as dependencies) & Incanter's namespaces. One library can contain many namespaces, for example, incanter-core includes `incanter.core`, `incanter.stats`, etc., while the `incanter.datasets` is in the incanter-io library (together with `incanter.io`), and `incanter.charts` is in the incanter-charts library.

If you include the `incanter` as dependency in your `project.clj`, then it will include all libraries & namespaces provided by Incanter.

The Incanter was split into many libraries to decrease the number of dependencies for cases, when people want to use only small part of its functionality, for example, only `incanter.stats` + `incanter.datasets`.

Some information about Incanter's libraries you can find in the [following presentation](http://alexott.net/common/incanter-denver/)

**Edited**: The problem with SSL arises from the old bug when dataset always was downloaded from Internet.  See [this issue](https://github.com/liebke/incanter/issues/237) for details...

I've committed the fix 2 days ago, but it still only in the master, not released.  To fix it in the release version, add following to your `project.clj`:

```
:jvm-opts ["-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false"]
```

This will prevent the error. If you don't want to download the datasets from Internet, you can explicitly pass the path to them via `get-dataset`'s options:

```
(get-dataset :iris :from-repo false 
              :incanter-home "/Users/ott/projects/incanter")
```

The `:incanter-home` path should point to the directory under which the Incanter's `data` folder is stored.

Comment: Incanter is a branch from the file `test-app` and within Incanter is the file data.. I used the following `:incanter-home "/test-app/incanter"` and am getting the error: system cannot find the path specified. @AlexOtt

Comment: You need to either use relative path, like `./test-app/incanter`, or expand this path to be absolute...

Answer (score 7):

Since you say you've been able to load dependencies from the REPL I assume you are now trying to load it from lein.

You need to include the dependency in your `project.clj`:

```
(defproject my-project "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :dependencies [[incanter "1.5.4"]])
```

At the top of the file where you want to use `incanter` functions have one of the following with the proper namespace and file name.

```
(ns my-namespace.filename
  (:require (incanter [core :refer :all]
                      [stats :refer :all]
                      [charts :refer :all]
                      [datasets :refer :all]))
```

This is the same as:

```
(ns my-namespace.filename
  (:require [incanter.core :refer :all]
            [incanter.stats :refer :all]
            [incanter.charts :refer :all]
            [incanter.datasets :refer :all]))
```

Same as:

```
(ns my-namespace.filename
  (:use [incanter.core]
        [incanter.stats]
        [incanter.charts]
        [incanter.datasets]))
```

I use the first variation for consistency since I usually don't want to `:refer :all` with all dependencies.